# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException Exception with Play WS library

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, asynchttpclient

GET call to `allBoxes` url fails with `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`

`val allBoxes = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes"`

```
object Streak {

  lazy val builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()

  lazy val client = new NingWSClient(builder.build())

  def allBoxes = {

    client.url(URLS.allBoxes)

    .withAuth(Constants.STREAK_API_KEY, "hello", WSAuthScheme.BASIC)

    .get

  }

}
```

---

**Play Action**

```
def boxes = Action.async { request =>

Streak.allBoxes.map { response => {

  Ok(s"${response.body}")

}}.recover { case th => Ok(s"failed due to ${th.printStackTrace()}")}

}
```

---

**routes**

GET        /boxes     controllers.Application.boxes()

---

**invocation**

`http://localhost:9000/boxes`

---

**Complete error**

java.net.ConnectException: https://www.streak.com:443
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.onFutureFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:128)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.access$200(NettyConnectListener.java:37)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener$1.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:101)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:409)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:395)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:362)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelDisconnected(SslHandler.java:575)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    ... 16 more

Comment: `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException` means you closed the connection before sending a message. Please include some more code. What are you doing before / after sending your request? Where does `client` come from? How do you access the results? Also a full stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Added more info @Roman